# What datastructure should be best to use to implement JSON parser ? I was asked this in one of the interview questions

Tags: json, algorithm, data-structures

```
A:{
   B:{
       C:"val1"
     },
   D:{
     E:{
         F:"val2"
       },
    },
   G:"val3"
 }
```

If the user enters A.B.C program should return `"val1"` and if the user enters `A.D` then it should return `E:{F:"val2"}` block.
I answered 2 solutions one is using HashMap and other using Trie data structure. But the interviewer was not satisfied with the answer. According to the interviewer, Trie would be more complex to use for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer it from Python's perspective. The structure above is a nested dictionary. For example, you can do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

def my_parser():
    return defaultdict(my_parser)

your_data = my_parser()
your_data['A']['B']['C'] = "val1"
your_data['A']['D']['E']['F'] = "val2"
your_data['A']['G'] = "val2"

print(json.dumps(your_data['A']['B'])) # prints {'C': "val1"}
print(json.dumps(your_data)) # prints {A:{B:{C:"val1"},D:{E:{F:"val2"},G:"val3"}}
```

If the user input is a string `'A.B.C'` then you can split it by dot (`.`) and return the value.